# How does Phonegap handle Views in Android?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm writing a plugin for Phonegap which allows you to take screenshots of the current screen on an Android device.

How does Phonegap handle the conversion of HTML to views? I'm currently finding the Root view by ID in the plugin using the following code:

```
View content = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Would this work in finding the root view?